# Warning: Internal React error: Expected static flag was missing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am using react-native-web:

```
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-dom": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.71.8",
"react-native-web": "~0.18.10",
```

Is a simple hook that does this:

```js
    const [cards, setCards] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        ;(async () => {
            try {
                const cards = await Server.userCards({ user_id })
                setCards(cards)
            } catch (error) {
                //
            }
        })()
    }, [user_id, setCards])
```

If a comment the line `setCards(cards)` I don't get any error.

```
react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: Internal React error: Expected static flag was missing. Please notify the React team.
    at Deck (http://localhost:19006/static/js/bundle.js:27119:20)
    at div
    at http://localhost:19006/static/js/bundle.js:13035:25
    at http://localhost:19006/static/js/bundle.js:33953:45
    at div
    at http://localhost:19006/static/js/bundle.js:13035:25
    at http://localhost:19006/static/js/bundle.js:33953:45
    at div
    at http://localhost:19006/static/js/bundle.js:13035:25
    at http://localhost:19006/static/js/bundle.js:33953:45
    at div
    at http://localhost:19006/static/js/bundle.js:13035:25
    at http://localhost:19006/static/js/bundle.js:33953:45
    at div
    at http://localhost:19006/static/js/bundle.js:13035:25
    at http://localhost:19006/static/js/bundle.js:33953:45
    at div
    at http://localhost:19006/static/js/bundle.js:13035:25
    at div
    at http://localhost:19006/static/js/bundle.js:13035:25
    at http://localhost:19006/static/js/bundle.js:9361:24
    at ScrollView (http://localhost:19006/static/js/bundle.js:39905:37)
    at ScrollView
    at http://localhost:19006/static/js/bundle.js:33953:45
    at div
    at http://localhost:19006/static/js/bundle.js:13035:25
    at http://localhost:19006/static/js/bundle.js:33953:45
    at div
    at http://localhost:19006/static/js/bundle.js:13035:25
    at http://localhost:19006/static/js/bundle.js:33953:45
    at div
    at http://localhost:19006/static/js/bundle.js:13035:25
    at http://localhost:19006/static/js/bundle.js:7859:24
    at http://localhost:19006/static/js/bundle.js:33953:45
    at div
    at http://localhost:19006/static/js/bundle.js:13035:25
    at http://localhost:19006/static/js/bundle.js:33953:45
    at Lobby (http://localhost:19006/static/js/bundle.js:26652:23)
    at Cards (http://localhost:19006/static/js/bundle.js:27938:79)
    at div
    at http://localhost:19006/static/js/bundle.js:13035:25
    at http://localhost:19006/static/js/bundle.js:33953:45
    at div
    at http://localhost:19006/static/js/bundle.js:13035:25
    at http://localhost:19006/static/js/bundle.js:33953:45
    at Views (http://localhost:19006/static/js/bundle.js:25587:79)
    at App (http://localhost:19006/static/js/bundle.js:25525:70)
    at withDevTools(App)
```